# Type cast issue with Oracle Command

Tags: c#, odp.net

We are using ODP.NET Oracle provider to connect to Oracle DB using Enterprise library 5.0.

The below code works fine:

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ORACLE_CONNECTION_CONFIG_NAME);
using (OracleCommand dbCommand = (OracleCommand)database.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_NAME))
{
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("parameters");
    database.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
}
```

But as per our requirement we need to decrypt the connection string using a custom logic before creating the database connection, so we cannot use DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() method.

So we are using the below code:

```
Database database= new  Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase("encrypted connection string");
using (OracleCommand dbCommand = (OracleCommand)database.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_NAME))    {
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("parameters");
    database.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
}
```

But at runtime, above Oracle command type casting is throwing the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand' to type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand'.

Can somebody tell me why this would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this

```
  DbProviderFactory providerFactory = 
      DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
  Database dbServer = 
      new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
                             .GenericDatabase("connection string", providerFactory);
```